# Parameter is not recognised by the function in .then angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to achieve is a dropdown list that produces lisof Metacategories. Once the user selects the meta category, the parameter should be passed onto the URI of the function present in $scope.meta().then(...). however, the parameter I am passing is category; ng-model="category". This parameter is not sent to the URI, I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

HTML:

```
 </select></center >
<center> <select ng-model="category"  > <!-- This produces drop down list from which the users selects a category which should then get passed to the meta1() function as a parameter to produce a further list for the drop down after that-->
<option size=50 value="" selected>Select a meta category</option>
 <option ng-repeat="meta in metas.metas" value="{{meta}}">{{meta}} </option>

</select></center>
<center> <select ng-model="category"  >
<option size=50 value="" disabled selected>Select a category</option>
 <option ng-repeat="category in categories.categories" value="{{category}}">{{category}} </option>

 </select></center>
```

Angular:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/post', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/post.html',
    controller: 'PostCtrl'
})
}])
.controller('UserListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.list = function () { // this gets the list of places which works completely fine.
    $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8001/getuncategorisedplaces').success(function (data) {

        $scope.places = data;
        console.log(data);
        $scope.message = 'List of Uncategorised places';
        $scope.meta = function () { // this gets list of meta categories, which is working fine.
            return $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8000/getmetas').success(function (data) {

                $scope.metas = data;
                console.log(data);
                $scope.message = 'List of Uncategorised places';
            })
        }
```

// the function below should get a parameter category from previous function which is selected in HTML. Once this happens, the parameter category should be passed on as formdata.category(below) which will get the list of categories.

```
        $scope.meta().then(function (data) {
            var formdata = {
                'category': this.category,
            }
            var inserturl = 'http://94.125.132.253:8000/getcategories?meta=' + formdata.category;
            $http.get(inserturl).success(function (data) {

                $scope.categories = data;
                console.log(formdata.category);
                console.log(data);
                $scope.message = 'List of Uncategorised places';
            });


        });
    })
}
$scope.list();
```

Comment: Here is a tip: Format the codes to have a proper indentation so that it is readable and attract people eyes to come and help!

Comment: Your `$scope.meta` function doesn't look like it's returning anything, but you're trying to call `.then` on the result of calling it.

Comment: oh how do I fix it. I have not used .then before but I want meta1() to be called after meta is called and one of the options has been selected to pass the parameter

Comment: I would suggest you to create a workable plunkr or jsfiddle to ease others to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `return`.

`$scope.meta` should `return` a promise for you to be able to use `.then()`

```
$scope.meta= function(){
    return $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8000/getmetas').success(function(...
        ...
}

$scope.meta().then(function (data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: This has stopped the error however, the code still does not work. It does not display the data that should come from second URI getcategories

Comment: Take a look at the edit. You should make the second call inside the callback.

Comment: yes that did help, however, now the problem has occured that it does not recognise the parameter which has been passed from the previous function which is meta.

Comment: I have all the original code in here, I have not used jsfiddle before but I have put the code together if that helps

Comment: Update your question to make it more clear and explain what you're trying to achieve. Currently it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have updated in now this edit includes what you suggest me to do as well

Comment: I dont see `data` returned by `.meta().then(function(data){..` being used anywhere. Isn't that what you're trying to do? Please include comments in your code explaining what you want to do.

Comment: I have commented the code I hope that makes more sense

Comment: If you're trying to access the value of `category` dropdown, you should have `$scope.category` in your controller. Also avoid giving same name to multiple elements in your form.

Comment: $scope.category replaces this.category in meta1() function?

Comment: Yes. `var formdata = {'category': $scope.category}`. Also you have two dropdowns with same model names that you need to fix.

Comment: I have done that. but the problem is occuring where second dropdown list should be loaded straight after an option is selected from the first dropdown. So forexample, the user select education parameter, it should get passed on to meta1() which produces a list in the second dropdown

Comment: Also in my console. I am getting the following as soon as the page loads >Object {places: Array[184]}
Object {metas: Array[10]} 
Object {categories: Array[0]}

Comment: The problem that is occurring now is that parameter is not passed. Also it should produce list for categories dropdown as soon as meta category is selected.

Comment: The `.success()` isn't chainable, convert it into `.then()` style to keep passing parameters.

Comment: That returns this >Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object} which means does not obtain the list. Also I would assume I need to do something in HTML to so that on selecting the meta category the next function gets called by passing the selected parameter into the next URI

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the error is caused by this:

```
$scope.meta().then(function meta1($scope,$http) {
```

because the meta method is not returning a promise.
The meta method could return a promise if you did this:

```
$scope.meta= function(){
  return $http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8000/getmetas').success(function (data) {
    $scope.metas = data;
    console.log(data);
    $scope.message = 'List of Uncategorised places';
    return data;
  });
};
```

and you could change the call to meta to this

```
$scope.meta().then(function(data) {
...
}
```